# Can future's absolute_import clear __package__?

Tags: python-2.x, pyramid, buildout

I have a Python 2 Pyramid App that is setup using `buildout` and a project folder activated using `Mr.Developer`; I am trying to `futurize` this project as part of Python 3 migration which changes:

`import test`

to:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from . import test
```

However for some reason `./bin/pserve development.ini` doesn't come up, it says:

```
...
  File "/apps/src/project/engine/config.py", line 3, in <module>
    import utilities
  File "/apps/src/project/engine/utilities.py", line 9, in <module>
    from project.engine import spreadsheets
  File "/apps/src/project/engine/spreadsheets.py", line 16, in <module>
    from project.engine import utilities
ImportError: cannot import name utilities
```

It is a proper package as far as I am aware because it does have a `setup.py` and I ran `develop activate project` + `buildout` again.

If I type `print(__package__)` in that code it prints fine, but if I add a line `from __future__ import absolute_import` it prints `None`. Is it possible that `future`'s `absolute_import` can simply clears out the `__package__` variable and that is why it is not detecting this as a package?

---

This is the MWE of the real issue: [Why does this circular import fail in Python 2 but not in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59831728/why-does-this-circular-import-fail-in-python-2-but-not-in-python-3), it seems to be a bug in Python 2 when there is circular import. If anyone has a clean solution please let me know.

Comment: Why is `__package__` set to `None` a problem? It's an internal detail, used by the import machinery to resolve relative imports, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/.

Comment: Because I want to do `from . import test` in the subsequent line?

Comment: That's not a problem. If `__package__` is `None` then the import machinery knows to calculate it.

Comment: (and my assertion about `None` was wrong, it's set to `''` when not in a package, `None` is just a 'not set' sentinel).

Comment: Why is it **not** a *package*? We do have `setup.py` and I use `develop activate project` and re-run `buildout` (all the standard source code activation stuff). Does it have something to with the way buildout does things (all the `sys.path` stuff)? I need to seamless develop this package and deploy it as an egg both with `future`'s `absolute_import` ? I can create a MWE if you want; but I am wondering if there is something trivial that I am missing.

Comment: We do need an MWE here, I suspect, as I might be missing something in your specific setup. `buildout` just uses `easy_install` to handle console scripts, if that's what you are referring to being problematic.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Finally I was able to nail down this issue to a strange behavior in Python 2. Here is the MWE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59831728/why-does-this-circular-import-fail-in-python-2-but-not-in-python-3. Let me know if you are aware of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `__package__` is set to `None`, that's just a flag value for *not yet set*. It is not a problem.

From [PEP 366 – *Main module explicit relative imports*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/#proposed-change), on the subject of `__package__`:

> When the import system encounters an explicit relative import in a module without `__package__` set (or with it set to `None`), it will calculate and store the correct value (`__name__.rpartition('.')[0]` for normal modules and `__name__` for package initialisation modules). If `__package__` has already been set then the import system will use it in preference to recalculating the package name from the `__name__` and `__path__` attributes.

If you see this set to `None` in the *main module* and it was meant to be part of a package, then set it yourself:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
    __package__ = "foo.bar.baz"
```

Comment: `__name__` won't `__main__` as well because I don't run it as a *scrip*t;  `pserve` runs it and it is throwing an error with `import` actually. (Sorry, I am a complete noob, just trying to figure out things.)

Comment: @Nishant: throwing *what* error? You haven't mentioned anything about errors, just asked if `__package__` can end up being set to `None`.

Comment: Updated, if you also *agree* that this should have worked, I will work on a MWE. I don't want you to waste any time on this because it looks like an `X-Y` problem to me; especially due to `buildout` complications.

Comment: @Nishant: sorry, that's not a helpful update, there is zero information about where this error happens, the error message is devoid of all context.

Comment: Let me do that @Martijn Pieters, thanks for your help!