# Why does this circular import fail in Python 2 but not in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, circular-dependency

Assume the following package structure with code inline:

```
main.py

from a.b import c

a/__init__.py

a/b/__init__.py

a/b/c.py

from a.b import d

a/b/d.py

from a.b import c
```

`python2 main.py` gives me an import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from a.b import c
  File "/home/runner/a/b/c.py", line 1, in <module>
    from a.b import d
  File "/home/runner/a/b/d.py", line 1, in <module>
    from a.b import c
ImportError: cannot import name c
```

However `python3 main.py` works fine. Does anyone know what is going on? How do I fix this issue in Python 2? I am trying to convert relative imports to absolute imports!

[Python 2 Repl.It](https://repl.it/repls/WoefulEffectiveDifference)

[Python 3 Repl.It](https://repl.it/repls/DirtyOddJavadoc)

Comment: I think this may fall under the remit of namespace packages versus regular packages in Python 3. Does [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#examples) example answer your question?

Comment: @soyapencil, That is interesting, it does seem connected with the idea of namespace packages I think - let me explore that. Thanks for the PEP.

Answer (score 1):

A quick work around is to move from the format

```py
from a.b import d
```

to

```py
import a.b.d
```

I tried it [here](https://repl.it/repls/PastGreenAssignment) and it seems to work for Python 2.

Comment: Any idea if it is bug in Python 2?